# Python - cannot access a specific div [Urllib, BeautifulSoup, maybe Mechanize?]

Tags: python, web, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, downloading-website-files

I have been breaking my head against this wall for a couple days now, so I thought I would ask the SO community.  I want a python script that, among other things, can hit 'accept' buttons on forms on websites in order to download files.  To that end, though, I need to get access to the form.

[This is an example of the kind of file I want to download.](http://www.cms.gov/apps/ama/license.asp?file=/McrPartBDrugAvgSalesPrice/downloads/Apr-13-ASP-Pricing-file.zip) I know that within it, there is an unnamed form with an action to accept the terms and download the file.  I also know that the div that form can be found in is the main-content div.

However, whenever I BeautifulSoup parse the webpage, I cannot get the main-content div.  The closest I've managed to get is the main_content link right before it, which does not provide me any information through BeautifulSoup's object.

Here's a bit of code from my script:

```
web_soup = soup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
parsed = list(urlparse(url))
ext = extr[1:]
for downloadable in web_soup.findAll("a"):
  encode = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',downloadable.text).encode('UTF-8','ignore')
  if ext in str.lower(encode):
    if downloadable['href'] in url:
      return ("http://%s%s" % (parsed[1],downloadable['href']))
for div in web_soup.findAll("div"):
  if div.has_key('class'):
    print(div['class'])
    if div['class'] == "main-content":
      print("Yep")
return False
```

Url is the name of the url I am looking at (so the url I posted earlier).  extr is the type of file I am hoping to download in the form .extension, but that is not really relevant to my question.  The code that is relevant is the second for loop, the one where I am attempting to loop through the divs.  The first bit of code(the first for loop) is code that goes through to grab download links in another case (when the url the script is given is a 'download link' marked by a file extension such as .zip with a content type of text/html), so feel free to ignore it.  I added it in just for context.

I hope I provided enough detail, though I am sure I did not.  Let me know if you need any more information on what I am doing and I will be happy to oblige.  Thanks, Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for getting `main-content` div and form action:

```
import re
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


url = "http://www.cms.gov/apps/ama/license.asp?file=/McrPartBDrugAvgSalesPrice/downloads/Apr-13-ASP-Pricing-file.zip"
web_soup = soup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

# get main-content div
main_div = web_soup.find(name="div", attrs={'class': 'main-content'})
print main_div

# get form action
form = web_soup.find(name="form", attrs={'action': re.compile('.*\.zip.*')})
print form['action']
```

Though, if you need, I can provide examples for lxml, mechanize or selenium.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This should be workable! Thank you.  When I first tried this solution, it was returning None and made me scratch my head a bit.  I narrowed down that issue thanks to you, though: in another part of my script, when I get the url, I'm not passing the exact url I need.  

Thank you for helping me with both my problem and a problem I didn't even know I had!  I appreciate it.